# I need to match strings that don't contain a keyword at an arbitrary position

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I need to match strings that ***don't*** contain a keyword (`beta2`) at an arbitrary position.

Consider:

```
var aStr    = [
                '/beta1/foo',
                'beta1/foo',
                '/beta1_xyz/foo',
                'blahBlah/beta1/foo',
                'beta1',

                '/beta2/foo',
                'beta2/foo',
                '/beta2_xyz/foo',
                'blahBlah/beta2/foo',
                'beta2',

                '/beat2/foo',
                'beat2/foo',
                '/beat2_xyz/foo',
                'blahBlah/beat2/foo',
                'beat2'
            ];

function bTestForMatch (Str)
{
    return /.*\b(?!beta2).*/i.test (Str);
}

for (var J=0, iLen=aStr.length;  J < iLen;  J++)
{
    console.log (J, bTestForMatch (aStr[J]), aStr[J]);
}
```

We need a regex that matches all strings that exclude `beta2`.  `beta2` will always start at a word boundary, but not necessarily end at one.  It can be at a variety of positions in the string.

The desired results would be:

```
 0    true    /beta1/foo
 1    true    beta1/foo
 2    true    /beta1_xyz/foo
 3    true    blahBlah/beta1/foo
 4    true    beta1
 5    false   /beta2/foo
 6    false   beta2/foo
 7    false   /beta2_xyz/foo
 8    false   blahBlah/beta2/foo
 9    false   beta2
10    true    /beat2/foo
11    true    beat2/foo
12    true    /beat2_xyz/foo
13    true    blahBlah/beat2/foo
14    true    beat2
```

---

The regex is for a 3rd-party analysis tool that takes JavaScript regular expressions to filter sub-results.   The tool takes a single line of regex.  There is no API and we don't have access to its source-code.

Is there a JavaScript regex that will filter the second beta results (`beta2`) from this analysis run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
/^(?!.*beta2).*$/
```

Comment: Perhaps you'd want to surround the keyword with `\b` anchors to avoid false positives on words like `beta20` or `alphabeta2`.

Comment: @Tim: Maybe a `\b` in the front, but because of Case 7 it cannot appear in the back (something more complicated, like `(?![^a-z])` is needed).

Comment: @KennyTM: Right, I hadn't noticed Case 7. I'd suggest `(?![^\W_])` then. But the regex is getting really ugly: `/^(?!.*(?<![^\W_])beta2(?![^\W_])).*$/`

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds.  Anyway, I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be.  I would anchor the front end with `\b`, though I'm not sure it's really needed.  As for the back end, I wouldn't bother trying to anchor it.  The only information we have about it is a negative: that it won't necessarily fall on a word boundary.

Comment: As stated in the question, `beta2` always *starts* on a word boundary.  It also can be mixed case.  So we tweaked this solution slightly to: `/^(?!.*\bbeta2).*$/i`.  Thanks, everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be considered cheating?

```
return !/beta2/i.test (Str);
```

Comment: That doesn't work as the `!` operator is outside the regex.  We'd tried that; the tool errors-out on anything but pure regex.

Comment: =)
It works because the ! is outside the regex (bTestForMatch returns what you want it to). However KennyTM's regexp seems to be what you asked for.